# Define block device of an ASM disk

Tags: oracle, oracle-asm

I have a bunch of asmdisks:

/dev/oracleasm/disks/DATA01

/dev/oracleasm/disks/DATA02

..

/dev/oracleasm/disks/DATA07

Probably, they were created as:

oracleasm createdisk DATA01 /dev/sda1

oracleasm createdisk DATA01 /dev/sda2

But I'm not sure.

How to define relied block device for created ASM disk? 
How to be sure that DATA01 is made of /dev/sda1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Newer versions of `ASMLib` support `oracleasm querydisk -p DATA01` which displays the underlying physicaldisk.

[oracleasm-querydisk](https://oss.oracle.com/projects/oracleasm-support/src/trunk/documents/oracleasm-querydisk.txt)

Example:

```
# oracleasm querydisk -p SSDDATA1
Disk "SSDDATA1" is a valid ASM disk
/dev/sdl1: LABEL="SSDDATA1" TYPE="oracleasm"
/dev/sdar1: LABEL="SSDDATA1" TYPE="oracleasm"
/dev/sdbn1: LABEL="SSDDATA1" TYPE="oracleasm"
/dev/sddf1: LABEL="SSDDATA1" TYPE="oracleasm"
/dev/mapper/mpathqp1: LABEL="SSDDATA1" TYPE="oracleasm"
#
```

Older versions may not have the `-p` option and they display only the major and minor numbers which you can use to find the physical disk:

[Mapping ASM disks to Physical Devices](https://blogs.oracle.com/alejandrovargas/mapping-asm-disks-to-physical-devices)

Example:

```
[root@orcldb2 ~]# /etc/init.d/oracleasm querydisk VOL1
Disk "VOL1" is a valid ASM disk on device [8, 97]

[root@orcldb2 ~]# ls -l /dev | grep 8, | grep 97
brw-rw----   1 root disk     8,      81 Nov  4 13:02 sdg1
```

This example I copied from the above blog post seems to be not totally accurate (`grep 97` returns minor number 81?), the concept however works.